# Collect metrics about request duration with App.Metrics and Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I need to collect correlating metrics of Request duration and Amount of returning items.
We use App.Metrics library. And the best way I currently found is use regular Gauge for each one.
The problem is that using Gauge we can loose changes occurred between Prometheus scrapings.

Does anyone have better idea than Gauge usage?
Thanks in advance.

I tried to tag each request metrics with unique Correlation Id, but Grafana treats each of them as separated metric and displays as separated graph.
I also tried to use App.Metrics.Histogram, which judging by description could solve the problem, but in practice it reports only Sum, Count and quantiles.

Here [the what the Histogram reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRVE7.png) It doesn't contains all occurrences. Only Sum, Count and quantiles

Comment: Histogram is the correct approach, if I understand what you want. Can you clarify what is you problem with it?

Comment: @markalex Thanks for your response. The problem is that Histogram reports only Sum , Count and quantiles. Not all changes occurred between scraps

Comment: Usually those are enough. Query like `increase(something_duration_sum[1m])/increase(something_duration_count[1m])` you'll get average time taken by your something. Or am I missing what you want to do?

Comment: Well it's not exactly what we need. The purpose of this metric is to get the request durations when request returns largest amounts of items. So if we'll use Average, and there will be a lot of small request and 1 or 2 large requests, the Average won't show the real picture.

Comment: Aha, that's what I was missing. In this case you should include information on number of items into your metrics (maybe in aggregated manner, like 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc.). But Histogram is still the one you need.